# How do you upgrade a flutter app with sqlite database?

Tags: flutter, dart, upgrade

I have a flutter app that uses an SQLITE database.
I want to issue a new version update of the app that is in both app store and google play store.

The new version will have new columns and new tables.

What would be the high level steps to include in my app so that the app would
a) copy all existing user records from the existing database
b) paste these into the new database - post upgrade

Of course I can put all my records in a dynamic list - which is what I have done, but what trigger do I use so that when a user upgrades to a new version (via the App Store or google play store) we can gracefully copy all user data from the existing database to the new version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from [sqflite documentation](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/migration_example.md)

TL:DR

**Migration example**

Here is a simple example of a database schema migration where:

> a column is added to an existing table
> a table is added

```
// Our database path
String path;
// Our database once opened
Database db;
```

**1st version**

The first version creates a Company table with a name column.

```
/// Create tables
void _createTableCompanyV1(Batch batch) {
  batch.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Company');
  batch.execute('''CREATE TABLE Company (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
)''');
}

// First version of the database
db = await factory.openDatabase(path,
    options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (db, version) async {
          var batch = db.batch();
          _createTableCompanyV1(batch);
          await batch.commit();
        },
        onDowngrade: onDatabaseDowngradeDelete));
```

**2nd version**

Let say we want to add a new table Employee with a reference to a Company entity. We also want to add a new column description in the Company entity.

We handle the creation of a fresh database in `onCreate` and handle the schema migration in `onUpgrade`. Also since we want to use foreign key constraints, we configure our access in `onConfigure.`

```
/// Let's use FOREIGN KEY constraints
Future onConfigure(Database db) async {
  await db.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
}

/// Create Company table V2
void _createTableCompanyV2(Batch batch) {
  batch.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Company');
  batch.execute('''CREATE TABLE Company (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    description TEXT
)''');
}

/// Update Company table V1 to V2
void _updateTableCompanyV1toV2(Batch batch) {
  batch.execute('ALTER TABLE Company ADD description TEXT');
}

/// Create Employee table V2
void _createTableEmployeeV2(Batch batch) {
  batch.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Employee');
  batch.execute('''CREATE TABLE Employee (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    companyId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (companyId) REFERENCES Company(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)''');
}

// 2nd version of the database
db = await factory.openDatabase(path,
    options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
        version: 2,
        onConfigure: onConfigure,
        onCreate: (db, version) async {
          var batch = db.batch();
          // We create all the tables
          _createTableCompanyV2(batch);
          _createTableEmployeeV2(batch);
          await batch.commit();
        },
        onUpgrade: (db, oldVersion, newVersion) async {
          var batch = db.batch();
          if (oldVersion == 1) {
            // We update existing table and create the new tables
            _updateTableCompanyV1toV2(batch);
            _createTableEmployeeV2(batch);
          }
          await batch.commit();
        },
        onDowngrade: onDatabaseDowngradeDelete));
```

You will have to restart your app when you change your application schema. Flutter Hot-reload won't work unless you properly close currently opened databases.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I understand correctly, i need to add onUpgrade parameters where we create the new schema on the fly?? I.e. I can't create a new Database using SQLITEStudio for example.. the new schema has to be created using CREATE TABLE syntax???

Comment: yes you need to add onUpgrade not sure about sqlstudio question but you can try it out and let me know

Comment: what after upgrading we needed a new upgrade for other tables...will we delete the current queries/methods inside on onUpgrade and replace it with the new ones?...and won't it confuse us a little after some time when seeing some edits and may be whole new tables as a code inside the database when it actually works and executes the required work?